# How to test simple Ajax response through RSpec in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to test some ajax requst for my controller and result of this action (through expect). I now how I can visit some page using Capybara, but how can I make DELETE request using AJAX for my resource? I need to make DELETE request for 'admin/menus/:id' using Ajax. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make a delete request via ajax to the destroy action, you would call

```
xhr :delete, :destroy, {id: 111}
```

Comment: Hey @Talgat, what is the difference between xhr and respond_to?

Comment: @DaryllSantos, `xhr` is a alias for `xml_http_request?()` which returns true for ajax requests. `response_to` is a way of responding to the client based on what they are asking for. Take a look [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/70520)